# Magento 2 : Get product collection with set if condition

Tags: magento2, product-collection

How to set if condition in magento 2 with product collection?

```
 public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
    {
        $products = $this->getCategoryData($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        echo $products->getSelect()->setOrder(IF('cat_index_position' = '0',1,0));exit;
        return $products;
    }
```

How to give if condition in above collection?

Above **`IF`** condition not working in collection and throws error for syntax error.

Thanks.

Comment: try adding quotes in front of `IF` and at the end of your expression

Comment: plz give me your answer i am not understand your sentance

Comment: try with `$products->getSelect()->setOrder("IF('cat_index_position' = '0',1,0)");exit;`

Comment: main.CRITICAL: Zend_Db_Select_Exception: Unrecognized method 'setOrder()' in /var/www/html/candleshack/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:1339

Comment: try `order` instead of `setOrder`

Comment: yes its working fine

Comment: @marius, ORDER BY CASE WHEN `cat_index_position` = '0' THEN 9999 ELSE 1 END how to define this query inside collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working solution based on marius comment,

```
public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
    {
        $products = $this->getCategoryData($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(14);
        $products->getSelect()->order("IF('cat_index_position' = '0',true,false)");

        return $products;
    }
```